# How do I get handheld StreetPass items?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

When you talk to HHA in the Nooklings shop,  do you get those hand held items I see people holding in the StreetPass area?  I'm confused about how StreetPass works.

Answer (score 3):

When you streetpass someone, their character and their house will appear in the Happy Home Showcase. When you streetpass someone that was already in your showcase, their character will appear holding an item.

To receive the item that a character is holding, simply talk to that character in the Happy Home Showcase and they will hand the item to you.

The items will appear in this order, and then repeat from the top of the list ([source](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/StreetPass#Happy_Home_Showcase)):

> - Balloon (2nd time)
> - Balloon (3rd time)
> - Pinwheel (4th time)
> - Bunny Balloon (5th time)
> - Bubble Blower (6th time)
> - Heart Balloon (7th time)
> - Ice Cream (8th time)
> - Soft Serve Ice Cream (9th time)
> - Tweeter (10th time)
>
> *The color or flavor for each item is from a random selection.*